# How connect use SSL Websocket from QT

Tags: qt, websocket

I developement WS client in QT. I have one problem: method QWebSocket::open not work width WSS.

```
m_WebSocket->open( QUrl( "wss://irinabot.ru/ghost/" ) );
```

if i replace scheme from wss to ws, that client success connected to server.

```
    connect( m_WebSocket, &QWebSocket::connected, this, &MapConfigData::onSocketConnected );
    connect( m_WebSocket, &QWebSocket::disconnected, this, &MapConfigData::onSocketDisconnected );
    connect( m_WebSocket, &QWebSocket::binaryMessageReceived, this, &MapConfigData::onSocketData );
    connect( m_WebSocket, QOverload<const QList<QSslError>&>::of( &QWebSocket::sslErrors ),
        this, &MapConfigData::onSslErrors );
```

No slot is called. Wireshark not capture traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **must** work with your code, assuming that the server really exposes a ssl websocket.

Anyway, another useful signal is provided:

```
QWebSocket::error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error)
```

Comment: Qt builded whout SSL support

Comment: The server MUST provide a ssl websocket.